# It is possible to detect unordered event patterns with WSO2?

Tags: wso2, correlation, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-cep

I would like to detect some patterns using wso2, but my current solution is only capable to detect them if the events arrived are consecutives.

Let's suppose the following pattern:

- Event 1: Scanning Event from Source 1 to Target 2
- Event 2: Attempt Exploit from Source 1 to Target 2

That would generate an Alert.

But in a real world scenario, the events won't come in order, there are too many computers in an enterprise.

There is a way to be able to detect the previous pattern with the following event sequence?

- Event 1: Scanning Event from Source 1 to Target 2
- Event 2: Not relevant
- Event 3: Not relevant
- ...
- Event N: Attempt Exploit from Source 1 to Target 2

My Current code is:

```
from every (e1=Events) -> e2=Events
within 10 min
select ...
having e1.type=='Scan' and e2.type=='attack' and e1.Source_IP4==e2.Source_IP4
insert into Alert;
```

I've also tried other kind of solutions like

```
from every e1=Events,e2=Events[Condition]
within 10 min
select ...
having e1.type=='Scan' and e2.type=='attack' and e1.Source_IP4==e2.Source_IP4
insert into Alert;
```

Maybe it could be done with a Partition? Partiotionate the streams taking into account the Source_IP4

Answer (score 1):

I've finally made it.

The problem was to use "having" to detect the pattern, It has to be moved to the "filter condition" section instead.

```
from (every)? <event reference>=<input stream>[<filter condition>] -> 
    (every)? <event reference>=<input stream [<filter condition>] -> 
    ... 
    (within <time gap>)?     
select <event reference>.<attribute name>, <event reference>.<attribute name>, ...
insert into <output stream>
```

Solution:

```
from every (e1=Events) -> e2=Events[e1.type=='Scan' and type=='attack' and e1.Source_IP4==Source_IP4]
within 10 min
select ...
insert into Alert;
```